# Android TV app with 2 modules, exclusion in Google Play

Tags: android, google-play, android-tv

My app is a game allowing to play on Android TV together with friends and family members that are using their android phones.

In Android Studio, I created 2 different modules : one for Android TV, and one for smarphones.

The manifest file for the Android TV module contains the required :

```
<uses-feature 
     android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen"
     android:required="false" />
```

The manifest file for the Android phones contains :

```
<uses-feature 
     android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen" 
     android:required="true" />
```

My goal is to have 2 separate apk files : one for TV and one for phones.

In the android developper console, I asked to publish my app in production.

But I received this answer from Google :

---

Thanks for submitting your app for Android TV. This is a notification that your application, xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx, with package ID xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx, is not being distributed on the Play Store for Android TV.

Version Name: 1.2.1
Version code: 1000003
Current track: PRODUCTION
REASON FOR EXCLUSION:

Google Uses Feature not Supported

Your app requires a Google TV uses-feature that prevents the app from being installed on Android TV devices: [android.hardware.touchscreen]. Please remove this from the features, and re-submit your app for re-review.

Please refer to the following developer page for details:

https://developer.android.com/training/tv/start/hardware.html

Does that mean that having several modules in this case is not correct ?

Comment: Just one more thing : "Version code: 1000003" means that it's the phone module

Comment: Can't you just set touchscreen required to false for your phone manifest?

Comment: Are you sure your Gradle files are set correctly? What do they look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved now, i received à quick answer from Google support team, my app is now accepted in production. No changes in any file (gradle or manifest).